# Using <style> tags in the <body> with other HTML

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
  <body>
    <style type="text/css">
      p.first {color:blue}
      p.second {color:green}
    </style>

    <p class="first">Hello World</p>
    <p class="second">Hello World</p>

    <style type="text/css">
      p.first {color:green}
      p.second {color:blue}
    </style>

    <p class="first">Hello World</p>
    <p class="second">Hello World</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

How is a browser supposed to render css which is non contiguous? Is it supposed to generate some data structure using all the css styles on a page and use that for rendering?

Or does it render using style information in the order it sees?

Comment: I'd say it is undefined behavior as it is not valid HTML. For more information which elements are valid and which are not: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element

Comment: Putting aside this problem, it is a bad practice to mix up `CSS` and `HTML`.

Comment: @0x2D9A3 Not necessarily true. It takes longer to request an external CSS page than CSS that is defined in the `<head>` tag

Comment: @KolobCanyon Agree, but as a general rule, CSS should be in a separate file. If you have tons of CSS, it is both easier to manage (maintaining, (post-)processing, minification, bundilng) and serve as a separate file, and your content (HTML) _might_ load faster, too, leading to better UX. However, as always with development, everything is context-specific, so YMMW :)

Comment: @KolobCanyon, this isn't an issue of whether CSS should be in a separate file.  In this case the question is about CSS in the ``<body>`` rather than in the ``<head>``.

Comment: https://jakearchibald.com/2016/link-in-body/

Comment: I know this is old, but you don't always have access to the <head> when using 3rd party tools. 
I needed a div to display differently whether in a mobile device, or in a PC, which easily done using @media queries, but those need the <style> tag. 
I ended up using a <script> tag and JS instead, because those are allowed inline!

Comment: @0x2D9A3 - the question isn't what is generally a good idea, but what is permitted when pragmatic circumstances would make it useful. In my case, `<head>..</head>` is specified outside the scope of what I can touch (a separate file used site-wide), making it very inconvenient to define page-specific css. Path of least resistance would be to add css styles at top of the file I am editing.

Comment: Some people have reported that it is a no-no to include style definitions in the `<body>...</body>` part but what are you supposed to do if the HTML is being produced incrementally and the required styles are not know at the time the `<head>...</head>` portion is produced? i am coding an application that produces an HTML log of the text that it receives/displays and individually styling each `<span>...</span>` is rather inefficient - better to define a new style each time one is needed and then use a reference to that each time it is subsequently needed...

Comment: Just look at real word examples. For example amazon.com has 11 style tags inside the body.

Answer (score 366):

> **WARNING**: This answer refers the `scoped` attribute on `style` tag which should not be used anymore!

As others have already mentioned, HTML 4 requires the `<style>` tag to be placed in the `<head>` section (even though most browsers allow `<style>` tags within the `body`).

However, HTML 5 includes the [**`scoped` attribute**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/style.html#style.attrs.scoped) (see update below), which allows you to create style sheets that are scoped within the parent element of the `<style>` tag.  This also enables you to place `<style>` tags within the `<body>` element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="scoped-content">
    <style type="text/css" scoped>
        h1 { color: red; } 
    </style>

    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

    <h1>
      World
    </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

If you render the above code in an HTML-5 enabled browser that supports `scoped`, you will see the limited scope of the style sheet.

There's just one ***major*** caveat...

At the time I'm writing this answer (May, 2013) almost no mainstream browser currently supports the `scoped` attribute.  (Although apparently [developer builds of Chromium](http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/04/html5-offers-scoped-css-for-precision-styling/) support it.)

HOWEVER, there is an interesting implication of the `scoped` attribute that pertains to this question.  It means that future browsers are mandated via the standard to allow `<style>` elements within the `<body>` (as long as the `<style>` elements are scoped.)

So, given that:

- Almost every existing browser currently ignores the `scoped` attribute
- Almost every existing browser currently allows `<style>` tags within the `<body>`
- Future implementations will be required to allow (scoped) `<style>` tags within the `<body>`

...then there is literally ***no harm*** * in placing `<style>` tags within the body, as long as you future proof them with a `scoped` attribute.  The only problem is that current browsers won't actually *limit the scope* of the stylesheet - they'll apply it to the whole document.  But the point is that, for all practical purposes, you *can* include `<style>` tags within the `<body>` provided that you:

- Future-proof your HTML by including the `scoped` attribute
- Understand that as of now, the stylesheet within the `<body>` will not actually be scoped (because no mainstream browser support exists yet)

* except of course, for pissing off HTML validators...

---

Finally, regarding the common (but subjective) claim that embedding CSS within HTML is poor practice, it should be noted that the *whole point* of the `scoped` attribute is to accommodate typical modern development frameworks that allow developers to import chunks of HTML as modules or syndicated content.  It is very convenient to have embedded CSS that *only* applies to a particular chunk of HTML, in order to develop encapsulated, modular components with specific stylings.

---

Update as of Feb 2019, according to the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#Deprecated_attributes), the `scoped` attribute is deprecated.  Chrome stopped supporting it in version 36 (2014) and Firefox in version 62 (2018).  In both cases, the feature had to be explicitly enabled by the user in the browsers' settings.  No other major browser ever supported it.

The website [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com) reports that the ["attribute has been removed from the current specification."](https://caniuse.com/style-scoped) since 2016.

Comment: I know you said there is *no harm*, in placing `<style>` tags in the body, except that it will cause the page to possibly render one way, then change it's appearance shortly there after.  You may see a flash of the page unstyled, then styled correctly.  It also forces the browser to do repaints and reflows which slows down the rendering of the page.  When browsers support the scoped attribute, and you use it, it prevents this because the browser knows that the section that it refers to hasn't been rendered yet, so it doesn't have to go back and see if any already rendered elements are affected

Comment: @Robert McKee, this shouldn't be an issue if you follow the logic of the `scoped` attribute and limit your use of scoped CSS styles to elements within the scope which appear after the `<style scoped>` element.

Comment: yes, when browsers actually implement support for the scoped attribute, and if you use that attribute then it won't cause the repaints and reflows (In theory), but until then (all current browsers) it actually does cause harm.

Comment: @RobertMcKee: have you actually tested that?  I'd expect that usually the entire html page (including all inline style) is parsed before rendering, since usually it's not huge and browsers wait a (very short) while before rendering precisely to avoid the flash-of-unstyled content that might occur due to css linked in the `head`.  *If* this is your only css, and *if* the page is large and *if* the network connection isn't very fast, then maybe you'll see a flash of unstyled content, but it'd surprise me in most practical situations.

Comment: Yes, it is very easy to see with either Chrome or Firefox extensions to see the paints and reflows that occur.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Why would there be a flash of different styling given that all browsers download and parse the entire HTML file before they start rendering? HTML is NOT a stream-able format - you have to build the DOM tree in it's entirety before you can do anything with it.

Comment: @NickG Because almost no browsers wait for the entire HTML file before they start rendering.  You do NOT need to build the DOM tree in it's entirety before you can do things with it.  Both of your statements are incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. I was misinformed. :/  In practice though, they do wait for a quite a while, so unless the site is slow you're very unlikely to see a flash of unstyled content. I also can't reproduce this on my own machine. If I force a delay, the page is simply blank. But perhaps a process or plugin is interfering with the HTML download.

Comment: As of today, only Firefox supports scoped style element (according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped). And since common browsers just support the STYLE element inside BODY, I would just use it, if necessary. If the CSS should be applied in a scope, you can just prefix every selector in the CSS source with ID/class of a wrapper. I actually did this in a web app that loaded HTML reports server-side and rendered them via AJAX. The CSS can be then prefixed with simple regex in JavaScript: cssString.replace(/(^|\})([^{]+)(\{)/g, '$1' + prefix + '$2$3')

Comment: Support for `@scoped`, or `scoped` seems to be dying out: [here](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/552) and [here](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/137)

Comment: Supporting @KiranSubbaraman : I've just (July 2016) read on mozilla dev: *"The **scoped attribute has been removed from the specification** after only limited and experimental adoption by Chrome and Firefox. **You should avoid using it**, as it will almost certainly be removed from these browsers soon."*  >> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#A_scoped_stylesheet

Comment: The `scoped` attribute has been removed from current HTML5 specifications.

Comment: Even as of Oct 3, 2017, the W3C recommendation doc states, "A style element is restricted to appearing in the head of the document." [Ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html51-20171003/document-metadata.html#the-style-element)

Comment: A note - though `scoped` has been removed and `<style>` is technically invalid within `<body>`, google.com, bing.com, and support.apple.com all rely on `<style>`s within `<body>`. I believe it's very safe to assume that the nesting will continue to work (without scoping). Hopefully, eventually, the spec will be updated to match.

Comment: @TristanBerger What does that mean - google, bing and apple relying on styles in the head? As search engine? For rendering? Do you have a source for this?  This does not seem to comcur with my (admittedly subjective) experience. The newest HTML5 spec allows `style` in the body, it lists it as flow content and the [element spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#elementdef-style) states `Contexts in which this element can be used: In the body, where flow content is expected.`

Comment: @Christoph Tristan claimed Google relies on `style` in the `body`, and interestingly they do! I went to google.com -> View Source -> copy & paste into an HTML beautifier -> remove the entire `<head>` section -> then search for `<style` within the remaining HTML body. Google.com currently uses `style` tags within the `<body>`

Comment: scoped link goes to 404 currently :(

Comment: It would be great to update this answer with up-to-date information that `scoped` has been removed from the spec and removed from the few implementations that had it.

Comment: I'd suggest bolding the edit about 'scoped' being deprecated in your entry, or even moving it to the very first line. This answer has lots of votes; some people might simply read the beginning and go with it.

Answer (score 114):

**BREAKING BAD NEWS** for "style in body" lovers: W3C has recently [lost the HTML war](https://techxplore.com/news/2019-06-w3c-whatwg-agreement-version-html.html) against WHATWG, whose versionless HTML "Living Standard" [has now become](https://www.w3.org/2019/04/WHATWG-W3C-MOU.html) the official one, which, alas, [does *not* allow](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-style-element) `STYLE` in the `BODY`. The short-lived happy days are over. ;) The [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/about.html) also works by the WHATWG specs now. *(Thanks @FrankConijn for the heads-up!)*

*(Note: this is the case "as of today", but since there's no versioning, links can become invalid at any moment without notice or control. Unless you're willing to link to its individual source commits at GitHub, you basically can no longer make stable references to the new official [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/), AFAIK. Please correct me if there's a canonical way of doing this properly.)*

**OBSOLETED GOOD NEWS:**

Yay, **`STYLE` is finally valid in `BODY`, as of HTML5.2!**
(And `scoped` is gone, too.)

From [the W3C specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) (*relish the last line!*):

> **4.2.6. The style element**
>
> ...
>
> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>
> Where metadata content is expected.
>
> In a noscript element that is a child of a head element.
>
> *In the body, where flow content is expected.*

---

**META SIDE-NOTE:**

The mere fact that despite the damages of the "browser war" we still had to keep developing against two [ridiculously competing](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/5swe9b/what_is_the_difference_between_the_w3c_and_the/) "official" HTML "standards" (quotes for the plural, as `1 standard + 1 standard < 1 standard`) means that the "fallback to in-the-trenches common sense" approach to web development has never really ceased to apply.

This may finally change now, but citing the conventional wisdom: web authors/developers and thus, in turn, browsers should ultimately decide what should (and shouldn't) be in the specifications, when there's no good reason against what's already been done in reality. And most browsers have long supported `STYLE` in `BODY` (in one way or another; see e.g. the `scoped` attr.), despite its inherent performance (and possibly other) penalties (which *we* should decide to pay or not, not the specs.). So, for one, I'll keep betting on them, and not going to give up hope. ;) If WHATWG has the same respect for reality/authors as they claim, they may just end up doing here what the W3C did.

Comment: I read the specs, but don't understand. Can you give an example code of a `style` block in the `body` that validates?

Comment: @FrankConijn: Good point, things changed, updated the answer! It's really confusing. Both the 5.2 and the 5.3 W3C specs treat `STYLE` as metadata & flow content, but the latest WHATWG "living" spec tells the old, boring "metadata only" story (allowing it only in HEAD). And, to add insult to injury, the W3C validator seems to follow the WHATWG flavor. I haven't decided yet whether to laugh or cry, but sure decided, personally, to "err" with the "browsers + W3C - validator" case, and allow STYLE in the BODY. (BTW, don't forget: _we should be the ultimate source of the standard_, actually.)

Comment: I really think they jumped the shark with this crap, they basically leave no choice but to use in line styles if you want to set a background image property dynamically in a templated system.  It was so much less invasive to drop a programatically generated style block just above your html output.

Comment: Fortunately, it seems unlikely that browsers are going to stop supporting a capability that many websites depend on. Would be inconvenient in CMS, or in third-party plugins, to not have in-body styles. Personally, when pragmatic (when I don't have easy access to `<head>`), I'll keep using this browser-supported capability, unless it starts breaking.

Comment: Somehow I doubt it, Emotion for example (the most popular CSS framework for React, the most popular JS framework in the world) inserts styles in the body by default for SSR. Fortunately Google and Microsoft have quite the monopoly on browsers now and hopefully they can persuade those idiots that it's a useful thing (just like there is a debate going on about the scope attribute which has really dumb behaviour no one agrees with)

Comment: All this discussion of standards is interesting, but from a web development standpoint, kind of irrelevant except to the degree to which you care about whether the W3C validator or other validators like your code. What matters in the "real world" is how browsers render your HTML and CSS. And I have never encountered any browser that has a problem with `<style>` elements in the body, even in types of HTML where it is supposedly not allowed. So, even if it is bad form and might be a theoretical risk, in practice I have never seen it do any harm.

Comment: FYI, you can `link` to external stylesheets in the body, if I'm not mistaken: [`link` can go where phrasing content is expected if it is "allowed in the body"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-link-element), and [it's "allowed in the body" if its `rel` attribute contains only "body-ok" keywords](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#allowed-in-the-body), and [`stylesheet` is a "body-ok" keyword](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#body-ok). So there's that at least. But yeah I also have yet to see a browser that doesn't support `style` in body anyways.

Answer (score 50):

When I see that the big-site Content Management Systems routinely put some <style> elements (some, not all) close to the content that relies on those classes, I conclude that the horse is out of the barn.

Go look at page sources from cnn.com, nytimes.com, huffingtonpost.com, your nearest big-city newspaper, etc.  All of them do this.

If there's a good reason to put an extra <style> section somewhere in the body -- for instance if you're include()ing diverse and independent page elements in real time and each has an embedded <style> of its own, and the organization will be cleaner, more modular, more understandable, and more maintainable -- I say just bite the bullet.  Sure it would be better if we could have "local" style with restricted scope, like local variables, but you go to work with the HTML you have, not the HTML you might want or wish to have at a later time.

Of course there are potential drawbacks and good (if not always compelling) reasons to follow the orthodoxy, as others have elaborated. But to me it looks more and more like thoughtful use of <style> in <body> has already gone mainstream.

Comment: Yes, you're right. As example I use <style> tag in <body> inside my plugin. Why, because it's easiest way to stylish plugin content. But one moment, all css classes are uniques for my plugin data.

Answer (score 13):

I guess this may be an issue about limited contexts, e.g. WYIWYG editors on a web system used by *not-programmers users*, that limits the possibilities of follow the standards. Sometimes (like TinyMCE), it's a lib that puts your content/code inside a `textarea` tag, that is rendered by the editor as a big `div` tag. And sometimes, it may be an old version of these editors.

I'm supposing that:

1. these *not-programmers users* don't have an open channel with the system admins (or institution's webdevs), to ask for including some CSS rules at the system's `stylesheets`. Actually, it would be impractical for the admins (or webdevs), considering the number of requests in that sense that they would have.
2. this system is legacy and still doesn't support newer versions of HTML.

In some cases, without use `style` rules, it may be a very poor design experience. So, yes, these users need customization. Okay, but what would be the solutions, in this scenario? Considering the different ways to insert CSS in a `html` page, I suppose these solutions:

---

## 1st option: ask your sysadm

Ask to your system adm for including some CSS rules at the system's `stylesheets`. This will be an **external or internal CSS** solution. As already said, it might be not possible.

---

## 2nd option: `<link>` on `<body>`

Use **external style sheet** on the `body` tag, i.e., use of the `link` tag *inside* the area you have access (that will be, on the site, inside the `body` tag and not in the `head` tag). Some sources says this is okay, but "not a good practice", like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link):

> A `<link>` element can occur either in the `<head>` or `<body>` element, depending on whether it has a link type that is **body-ok**. For example, the `stylesheet` link type is body-ok, and therefore `<link rel="stylesheet">` is permitted in the body. However, this isn't a good practice to follow; it makes more sense to separate your `<link>` elements from your body content, putting them in the `<head>`.

Some others, restrict it to the `<head>` section, like [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp):

> **Note:** This element goes only in the head section, but it can appear any number of times.

### Testing

I tested it here (desktop environment, on a browser) and it works for me.
Create a file `foo.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <link href="bar.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <h1 class="test1">Hello</h1>
    <h1 class="test2">World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And then a CSS file, at the same directory, called `bar.css`:

```css
.test1 { 
    color: green;
};
```

Well, this will just looks possible if you have how upload an CSS file somewhere at the institution system. Maybe this would be the case.

---

## 3rd option: `<style>` on `<body>`

Use **internet style sheet** on the `body` tag, i.e., use of the `style` tag inside the area you have access (that will be, on the site, inside the `body` tag and not in the `head` tag). This is what **Charles Salvia**'s and **Sz**'s answers here are about. Choosing this option, consider their concerns.

---

## 4th, 5th and 6th options: JS ways

Alert
These ones are related to modifying the `<head>` element of the page. Maybe this **will not** be allowed by the institution's system administrators. So, it's recommended to ask them permission first.

Okay, supposing permission granted, the strategy is access the `<head>`. How? JavaScript methods.

### 4th option: new `<link>` on `<head>`

This is another version of the 2nd option. Use **external style sheet** on the `<head>` tag, i.e., use of the `<link>` element *outside* the area you have access (that will be, on the site, not inside the `body` tag and yes inside the `head` tag). This solution complies with the recommendations of **MDN** and **w3schools**, as cited above, on 2nd option solution. A new [`Link` object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/dom_obj_link.asp) will be created.

To solve the matter through JS, there are many ways but at the following codelines I demonstrate one simple.

#### Testing

I tested it here (desktop environment, on a browser) and it works for me.
Create a file `f.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1 class="test1">Hello</h1>
    <h1 class="test2">World</h1>
    <script>
        // JS code here
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the `script` tag:

```js
var newLink = document.createElement("link");
newLink.href = "bar.css";
newLink.rel = "stylesheet";
newLink.type = "text/css";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newLink);
```

And then at the CSS file, at the same directory, called `bar.css` (as at the 2nd option):

```css
.test1 { 
    color: green;
};
```

As I already said: this will just looks possible if you have how upload an CSS file somewhere at the institution system.

### 5th option: new `<style>` on `<head>`

Use new **internal style sheet** on the `<head>` tag, i.e., use of a new `<style>` element *outside* the area you have access (that will be, on the site, not inside the `body` tag and yes inside the `head` tag). A new [`Style` object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/dom_obj_style.asp) will be created.

This is solved through JS. One simple way is demonstrated following.

#### Testing

I tested it here (desktop environment, on a browser) and it works for me.
Create a file `foobar.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1 class="test1">Hello</h1>
    <h1 class="test2">World</h1>
    <script>
        // JS code here
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the `script` tag:

```js
var newStyle = document.createElement("style");
newStyle.innerHTML = 
    "h1.test1 {"+
        "color: green;"+
    "}";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newStyle);
```

### 6th option: using an existing `<style>` on `<head>`

Use an existing **internal style sheet** on the `<head>` tag, i.e., use of a `<style>` element *outside* the area you have access (that will be, on the site, not inside the `body` tag and yes inside the `head` tag), if some exists. A new `Style` object will be created or a [`CSSStyleSheet` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) will be used (in the code of the solution adopted here).

This is at some point of view risky.
**First**, because it may not exists some `<style>`  object. Depending of the way you implement this solution, you may get `undefined` return (the system may use *external style sheet*).
**Second**, because you will be editing the system design author's work (authorship issues).
**Third**, because it may not be allowed at your institution's IT politics of safety.
So, do ask permission to do this *(as at in other JS solutions)*.

Supposing, again, permission was granted:

You will need to consider some restrictions of the method available to this way: [`insertRule()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule). The solution proposed uses the default scenario, and a operation at the first `stylesheet`, if some exists.

#### Testing

I tested it here (desktop environment, on a browser) and it works for me.
Create a file `foo_bar.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="test1">Hello</h1>
    <h1 class="test2">World</h1>
    <script>
      // JS code here
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inside the `script` tag:

```js
function demoLoop(){ // remove this line
    var elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName("style");
    if (elmnt.length === 0) {
        // there isn't style objects, so it's more interesting create one
        var newStyle = document.createElement("style");
        newStyle.innerHTML =
            "h1.test1 {" +
                "color: green;" +
            "}";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newStyle);
    } else {
        // Using CSSStyleSheet interface
        var firstCSS = document.styleSheets[0];
        firstCSS.insertRule("h1.test2{color:blue;}"); // at this way (without index specified), will be like an Array unshift() method
    }
} // remove this too
demoLoop(); // remove this too
demoLoop(); // remove this too
```

Another approach to this solution it's using `CSSStyleDeclaration` object (docs at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/obj_cssstyledeclaration.asp) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration)). But it may not be interesting, considering the risk to override existing rules on the system's CSS.

---

## 7th option: inline CSS

Use **inline CSS**. This solve the problem, although depending of the page size (in code lines), the maintenance (by the author itself or other assigned person) of code can be very difficult.

But depending of the context of your role at the institution, or its web system security policies, this might be the unique available solution to you.

### Testing

Create a file `_foobar.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="color: green;">Hello</h1>
    <h1 style="color: blue;">World</h1>    
  </body>
</html>
```

---

## Answering strictly the question asked by Gagan

> How is a browser supposed to render css which is non contiguous?
>
> 1. Is it supposed to generate some data structure using all the css styles on a page and use that for rendering?
> 2. Or does it render using style information in the order it sees?

*(quote adapted)*

For a more accurate answer, I suggest Google these articles:

- How Browsers Work: Behind the scenes of modern web browsers
- Render-tree Construction, Layout, and Paint
- What Does It Mean To “Render” a Webpage?
- How browser rendering works — behind the scenes
- Rendering - HTML Standard
- 10 Rendering — HTML5

Answer (score 9):

Not valid HTML, anyway pretty much every browser seems to consider just the second instance.

Tested under the last versions of FF and Google Chrome under Fedora, and FF, Opera, IE, and Chrome under XP.

Answer (score 7):

As others have said, this isn't valid html as the style tags belong in the head.

However, most browsers dont' really enforce that validation.  Instead, once the document is loaded then the styles are merged and applied.  In this case the second set of styles will always override the first because they were the last definitions encountered.

Answer (score 6):

I guess this will vary from browser to browser: The global display rules will probably be updated as the browser goes along through the code.

You can see such changes in the global display rules sometimes when an external style sheet is loaded with a delay. Something similar might happen here but in such short succession that it doesn't actually get rendered.

It's not valid HTML anyway, so I'd say that it is a futile thing to think about. `<style>` tags belong in the `head` section of the page.

Answer (score 5):

### What browsers really do...

Again, this is a theory vs practice debate. No real winners.
First of all let me show you a CodePen:

https://codepen.io/dkellner/pen/gOzXGjz?editors=1100

**CSS:**

```css
.jeff { background:red; transform:rotate(2deg); color:white; }
```

**HTML:**

```html
<style> .jeff { margin:20% 0 0 20%; width:400px; } </style>
<div class="jeff">
  
    This is Jeff.

    <style> .jeff {background:blue; padding:40px;} </style>
</div>

<style> .jeff {background:green} </style>
```

#### Explanation

In this example, I used 4 different style blocks. One directly in the CSS box of CodePen, they'll put it somewhere nice, probably in the head, whatever. The next one is right *before* the div, then one *inside* the div, and the last one is *after* it. Jeff is going through a lot right now. He's green, because that's what the last rule told him, but he's also rotated and positioned and the text inside is white, so we can safely say he's read *everything* the style tags told him, and:

- All `style` blocks were applied;
- They were applied in the correct order;
- They properly override each other;
- The whole thing acts like one big stylesheet.

That's what happens.

Again, browsers are patient beasts. They want you to enjoy the internet, and people creating websites are not very well disciplined so browsers evolved to tolerate their insane behaviour.

#### Bottom line

1. Yes you can put style tags in the body
2. Yes it works as you'd expect
3. Avoid if possible, it's an [ongoing debate](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1605), who knows where we end up.

Answer (score 4):

The `<style>` tag belongs in the `<head>` section, separate from all the content.

References: [W3C Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#edef-STYLE) and [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_style.asp)

Comment: Does not address question. And those stiff guidelines are overrun by reality. There are MANY cases where it is not possible for authors to define/include their style in the html head.

Comment: This may have been true in 2010, but it is far from an acceptable answer today.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, a browser isn't "supposed" to do anything. The HTML is invalid. Either error recovery is triggered, or the parser makes of it as it will.

In a valid instance, multiple stylesheets are just treated as appearing one after the other, the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) is calculated as normal.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is HTML is not valid does not have any affect on the outcome ... it just means that the HTML does adhere to the standard (merely for organizational purposes).  For the sake of being valid it could have been written this way:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  p.first {color:blue}
  p.second {color:green}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="first" style="color:green;">Hello World</p>
<p class="second" style="color:blue;">Hello World</p>
```

My guess is that the browser applies the last style it comes across.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. I checked on Mozilla's page.
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

Comment: Update from the page you linked: "The <style> element must be included inside the <head> of the document."

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get completely legal "scoped styles" in modern browsers with a small amount of effort. Consider this HTML document:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <style>p{background:red}</style>
    <body>
        <template>
            <style>p{background:green}</style>
            <p>I am green</p>
        </template>
        <p>I am red!</p>
        <script>
         document.querySelectorAll('template').forEach((template)=>{
             const div = document.createElement('div');
             div.remove(); // detach div from document
             let shadow = div.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
             shadow.replaceChildren(template.content);
             template.replaceWith(div);
         });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I used a `template` to enclose HTML that I wanted to contain its own `style` element that doesn't affect any HTML outside that `template`. Of course, by default, a `template` is ignored during rendering. So the JavaScript code

1. locates each template in the document
2. creates a detached empty `div`
3. gives the `div` a "shadow root" (the key to localizing a `style`)
4. copies the `template` contents to the shadow root
5. replaces the original `template` with the `div` that contains the same stuff (except in a shadow root)

Almost any HTML content--including `style`-- is legal inside a `template`.

Tested with the latest Chrome/Firefox/Edge. Send me a free MacBook Pro and I'll test it with Safari! :-)