# UpdatePanel and modifying controls outside of the Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, reporting-services, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a control inside of an `UpdatePanel`. The `UpdatePanel` has an `AsyncPostBack` trigger associated with the inner control. This works just fine.

I have another control containing a SSRS `ReportViewControl` that I would like to conditionaly hide based on the results from the postback event of the `UpdatePanel` mentioned above.

The `ReportViewerControl` is not inside of an `UpdatePanel` and **I would like to keep it this way**. How can I hide the `ReportViewerControl` based on the postback event of an `UpdatePanel` inside of another control?

I am assuming that many problems would spring up if I place the `ReportViewerControl` inside of an `UpdatePanel`, anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Hide the content through server side code but rather to use javascript (possibly injected by the server through a postback) as suggested by Machinegon.
2. Have a second `UpdatePanel` around the other content that you want to hide.  (You can't make the current one bigger, but making a second shouldn't cause problems.)  Have that second update panel set the same button as the trigger.  (You can have a trigger that's outside of the update panel, you just can't update content outside of the update panel.)  If the update is conditional (you only sometimes change the content when the button is clicked) then you can set the only trigger for the second panel to be a hidden button which you `Click` in code from the handler of the first button click.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a script inside you update panel content template and hide your control form javascript.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     Sys.Application.Add_load(MyFunctionThatHides);
   </script
```

Answer (score 1):

> The ReportViewerControl is not inside of an UpdatePanel and I would
>   like to keep it this way.

I did a simple trick. I created a another Updatepanel and put a literal control side the update panel and this  update panel code Is Above the "Control you want to hide"

something like this

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" >
    <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="literal1"></asp:Literal>
     </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then in Code behind I inject CSS

something like this

```
literalDvControl.Text = "<style> #YourControlID{ display:none;}</style>";
```

This seems to be working. Basically literal control is injecting style tag and browser is very quick to react.

but do read about this .
[Using <style> tags in the <body> with other HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code after processing the Async AJAX call on server and just before returning the response to client/browser

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowHideReportViewerJSScript", <JS code to show/hide reportviewer>, true);
```

I assume you have scriptmanager placed on the ASPX page

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This kind of breaks my pattern because I do not assume that a ReportViewer control exists when this control's postback is called. Is it possible to do something similar but instead of looking for a control look for another JS method that may or may not have been registered from another control. If that is possible then I can register another JS function when the control with the ReportViewer is loaded?