# Put CSS in body and maintain valid HTML5 code?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to enclose `<style>` tags within `<body>` and still have valid HTML5 code?

It's just very convenient to create modular website like

1. Template #1 - style, javascript, html
2. Template #2 - style, javascript, html

And not:

1. Template #1 - javascript, html
2. Template #2 - javascript, html
3. All style mixed in `<head>`

Comment: Not until scoped styles are standardized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using <style> tags in the <body> with other HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Here:

http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/

Scoped is not quite standardized, yet. Give it some time.

Comment: That's what W3C validator suggests, too but I didn't quite understand that till now. Thanks for the link! Too bad it isn't yet there.