# How to change the bgcolor of tr from td

Tags: php, html, background, html-table

I have a recurring table rows.

```
 <table id="ads-content"><tr class="<?php
        if ($i & 1) {
            echo'alternate';
        } else {
            echo '';
        }
   ?>"> 

   <td align="left"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
      <td align="left">
              //some code to retrieve and print db values. at here $pcount is initialized. I can't initialize $pcount before tr.
             </td> 
                <td><?php
                    if ($pcount != 1) {
                        echo "<img  src='" . plugin_url('images/pencil2.png') . "'>";
                    } else {

                        echo "<img  src='" . plugin_url('images/tick.jpg') . "'>";
        }
                    ?> </td>
                       </tr></table>
```

**Problem:**

I need to change the bg color of `<tr>` in which contains the image "tick.jpg".

I tried so many ways but nothing fills the whole row.

How can I do this?

**Answer**

I fixed it. I will share the code I used to fix below so that it will help some other persons:

```
     <table id="ads-content"><tr class="<?php
            if ($i & 1) {
                echo'alternate';
            } else {
                echo '';
            }
       ?>"> 
            <td align="left"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
              <td align="left">
                      //some code to retrieve and print db values. at here $pcount is initialized.i can't initialize $pcount before tr.
                     </td> 
                        <td><?php
                            if ($pcount != 1) {
                                echo "<img  src='" . plugin_url('images/pencil2.png') . "'>";
                            } else {
                <div class="to_class" style="display=none;"><?php echo "new"; ?></div>
                                echo "<img  src='" . plugin_url('images/tick.jpg') . "'>";
                }
                            ?> </td>
                               </tr></table>  
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   $('#ads-content tr').each(function() {
       var obtained= $(this).find("td").eq(2).find(".to_class").text();
       $(this).addClass(obtained);
       });
      });
   </script>
```

Note: eq() starts from zero,
then I gave background colour for class "new" in the css part.

Comment: can you not use the same `if($pcount != 1)` statement to apply a class to the `<tr>` and then give that a background colour? in the same way that you're applying the `alternate` class

Comment: i tried that friend. but the $pcount value is setting on the 2nd <td>.

Comment: why not initialise the pcount at the beginning of the row - until you show us the code that gets pcount we won't know why you can't just call it at the start

Answer (score 0):

IMHO if you cannot init the $pcount before you actually print the TR, you should definitely think about changing this. You do something wrong.
Maybe this will help:

```
//HERE: some code to retrieve
$output = '';
if ($pcount != 1) {
    $output .= '<tr style="background:#FFF;">';
} else {
    $output .= '<tr style="background:#AAA;">';
}
$output .= '<td align="left">'; 
$output .= ''; // HERE: print db values.
$output .= '</td>';
$output .= '</tr>';
echo $output;
```

Otherwise, if you cannot help it at all, you can do with jQuery e.g.:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    if( $(this).find('img[src="images/tick.jpg"]').length > 0 ) {
        $(this).css('background','#FFF'); 
    } else {
        $(this).css('background','#AAA');
    }
});
```

Comment: OP states in his question "at here $pcount is initialized. i can't initialize $pcount before tr", so thanks for the JS solution too

Answer (score 0):

Since you add an image both times. Add a different class to the tick.jpg image trace it back by jQuery, I suppose.

`<img src="tick.jpg" class="tick_img">`

`$('.tick_img').parents('tr').css('background', 'red');`

Comment: OP isnt looking for an odd versus even solution otherwise they would use their `.alternate` class already being applied

Comment: you'll need to call `.parent()` twice to get up to the `tr` or use `.closest('tr')`

Answer (score -1):

put `$i` in the `<tr>` as something like `id="row-id-<?php echo $i; ?>"`

then inside the `if($pcount != 1)` include something like:

```
<style type="text/css" scoped> /* added for future proofing */
    #row-id-<?php echo $i; ?>{
        background-color:red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Inline styles and style tags in the page are bad, m'kay?

Comment: cross browser, no JS solution given OP cant change the order of his GET code

Comment: When having 500 records you would have 500 opening and closing `<style>` tags. With that, Id's in CSS are a no-no!

Comment: I would love to see documentation about how id's in css are a "no-no" if used correctly. They are designed to target individual items on the page (hence the naming convention that i suggested). as for in body `style` tags.. this solution would say otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/a/16844668/648350

Comment: Inline styles are different than in body style tags. You would just create 500 of them which wouldn't make sense. About the ID's; I guess it's a matter of (conventional) taste more than a rule of thumb.

Comment: i suppose if we had OP's full `php` code we could collect the id's generated in an array and then output them into a single `style` tag after the initial loop had completed. But we dont. I totally agree with inline styles (was why i didnt understand you bringing them up in your first comment), as I understand about the potential complications with screen readers etc. However, in body style tags dont have accessibility, validation or cross-browser issues, like you said it comes down to "taste", and this solution doesnt require JS. (I am assuming "taste" shouldnt be a reason for a downvote?)