# jQuery's .html function doesn't write content to textarea correctly if there is a style tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the basic setup: We're adding some HTML inside textareas using JavaScript/jQuery. Test 1 does not have a `<style>` tag, while Test 2 does.

```
<textarea"><div><style></style><span>Baseline</span></div></textarea>
<textarea id="test1"></textarea>
<textarea id="test2"></textarea>

<script>
    var test1HTML = '<div><span>Test1</span></div>';
    var test2HTML = '<div><style></style><span>Test2</span></div>';

    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = test1HTML;
    document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = test2HTML;
</script>
```

The above works as expected: all text areas show the HTML code.

*But* if we use jQuery's `.html` function to add the content, then Test 2 does not display correctly. It appears to add the content as actual elements, rather than text.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test1').html(test1HTML);
    $('#test2').html(test2HTML); // Causes some kind of problem
});
```

If we replace `.html` with `.text`, then both tests again work as expected.

What's going on with Test 2 using `.html`? Why does adding a `<style>` tag change the way `.html` adds the content? Why do all other methods work correctly?

(FWIW - browser is Chrome 39.0.2171.95 m)

Comment: Setting the contents of a `<textarea>` tag with `.html()` seems like an odd thing to do.

Comment: Textareas are form controls. You should be using `.val()` to set its "content" (value).

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16844668 Using <style> tag inapproprietly might be a problem.

Comment: Also good to know: The "inner HTML" of a `<textarea>` is only used as *initial value* of the element. If you change `innerHTML` after the value was modified, it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery checks the value you're supplying to `.html()` for `<script>`, `<style>` and `<link>` tags (among several other things). Only if it **does not** contain them will it continue to set the `.innerHTML` property of the matched elements.

However, if the value **does** contain any of those tags, then jQuery chooses to execute `$(element).empty().append(content);` instead, which appends the text value (node) as a child element.

That should at least explain the difference in behavior.

Here's an excerpt from the source code (v1.11.1):

```
html: function( value ) {
    return access( this, function( value ) {
        var elem = this[ 0 ] || {};
        // ...ommitted
        // See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
        if ( typeof value === "string" && !rnoInnerhtml.test( value )) //...
            // ...
            elem.innerHTML = value;
            // ...
        }
        // ... else ... 
        this.empty().append( value );
        // .... end if
    }, null, value, arguments.length );
},
```

The `rnoInnerhtml` regular expression is: `/<(?:script|style|link)/i,`

Comment: That explains it, thanks! Do you have a reference by chance? Or even an explanation of **why** jQuery does this?

Comment: @Luke: I added the source code from which I derived my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `.val` method:

```
$('#test1').val(test2HTML);
```

Comment: OP not asking for method to accomplish this, but asking about the differences b/w the methods attempted and associated results.