# <style> tag within body and W3 Standards

Tags: html, css, web-standards

After reading this question I am confused:

[Using <style> tags in the <body> with other HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html)

Most people in there say it is bad practice to have style tags in the body section, and that it does not adhere to W3 standards, however I read this differently:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/style.html#style

Above link says:

```
Permitted parent elements:
Any element that can contain metadata elements, div, noscript, section, article, aside
```

The body element allows all these apart from 'metadata elements', but this list does not state that all of these elements need to be accepted in order for the style tag to be allowed. So surely it is OK by W3 standards to have the style tag within the body simply because for example the body element allows the use of div?

Maybe I'm reading this much later (5 years on) and this rule has been changed because of the 'scoped' attribute for style tags, so I wanted to ask to see if I was wrong in my interpretation of their standard or not.

Comment: I think its OK from a standards perspective. From a usability point though, you're going to have unstyled content that renders before your styles have loaded and thus you'll get an ugly flash of styling. That's more than likely why its frowned upon.

Comment: Is this a question of `<style scoped>` or just plain `<style>` being in the `<body>`?

Comment: @zzzzBov <style> only - my use case is I am using a content management system (Drupal) and would like an efficient solution for implementing some images I am using, controlling it using CSS would be perfect, but I need to find a nice way of getting that CSS in there....don't have enough control to add it inline, besides the fact that inline is the slowest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [front page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/Overview.html#toc) of the document you linked to:

> This document has been discontinued and is only made available for historical purposes. For an up to date reference on HTML elements (and more) please consult Web Platform Docs.

Some **draft** versions of HTML 5 allowed style elements in the body *under certain conditions*.

There were various problems with the design of that functionality and it did not make it into the final version of HTML 5.

Comment: I can never keep the specs straight. AFAICT [the w3c spec still allows the `<style>` element in the body so as the `[scoped]` boolean attribute is present](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#the-style-element). The [WHATWG spec also seems to back this up](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-style-element).

Comment: @zzzzBov — The w3c spec you quote is the HTML 5.1 **working draft**, not the current stable HTML 5 spec. WHATWG is a "living" standard so isn't a safe reference.

Comment: @Quentin, so which spec *is* the safe one?

Comment: [ah, I think I found it](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-style-element). As I said before, I can never keep the specs straight. IMO, the WHATWG spec being a living standard doesn't make it unsafe, it makes it more in touch with the current reality of the browser landscape.

Comment: @zzzzBov — http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped - the living spec is very aspirational, it defines things with practically no support and which are subject to change.

Comment: @Quentin, [https://github.com/PM5544/scoped-polyfill](https://github.com/PM5544/scoped-polyfill) the web community is pretty good at filling in the gaps to give browsers a chance to catch up.