# how to write html Content To open New Window with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror

on click run button open new window with data of html, css and javascript code editor. css is pass in new window but html data not, in html using code mirror that can pass in javascipt

run botton code is here

```
<div style="float:left; width:100%; height:93px;">
    <span class="containerTitle" style="top:65px;">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="button_example" id="result" style="color: white;">Result</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

on this button call function "nwin"

```
$("a#result").click(nWin);
```

nwin function is,

```
<script>
    function nWin() {
        var w = window.open();
        $(w.document.body).html("<style>" + $('#css').val() + "</style>"+ $('#html').val() );
    }
</script>
```

html data codemirror is,

```
<div class="codecontainer" id="htmlContainer" style="max-width:40%;">
    <span class="containerTitle">HTML</span>
    <textarea class="code" id="html" style="display: none;"></textarea>     
</div>
```

that pass value in editor variable,

```
<script>
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("html"), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        mode: "text/html",
        matchBrackets: true
    });
</script>
```

how to set the value editor in function nwin in  html window

Comment: `<style>` elements should go in `<head>`, not `<body>`.

Comment: @Barmar That is incorrect, style elements can be placed everywhere. But yes they "should" be placed in the head element.

Comment: @StijnBernards http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html

Comment: @Barmar Hmm? Seems like I made a mistake sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `save` from the code editor to the text area before getting the value.  It is working in my example

http://jsfiddle.net/em1uz745/2/

*Put the same code in a snippet for reference, but it appears that the `window.open` is blocked:*

```js
$("a#result").click(nWin);

var cssEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("css"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  mode: "text/css",
  matchBrackets: true
});

var htmlEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("html"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  mode: "text/html",
  matchBrackets: true
});

function nWin() {
 // Commit the code to the textarea so that it can be extracted using value
    cssEditor.save();
    htmlEditor.save();
 
 var w = window.open();
    $(w.document.head).append("<style>" + $('#css').val() + "</style>");
 $(w.document.body).html($('#html').val() );
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.button_example {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button_example:hover {
    background: #aaa;
}

.codecontainer {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button_wrap">
  <span class="containerTitle">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="button_example" id="result">Result</a>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="codecontainer" id="cssContainer">
  <span class="containerTitle">CSS</span>
  <textarea class="code" id="css"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="codecontainer" id="htmlContainer">
  <span class="containerTitle">HTML</span>
  <textarea class="code" id="html"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: how to use javascript ??also like html and css

Comment: please see the JSfiddle I linked or the snippet in my answer.

Comment: ya it  i can also   javascript editor like html and css                                                                          

<div class="codecontainer" id="htmlContainer">
  <span class="containerTitle">HTML</span>
  <textarea class="code" id="html"></textarea>
</div>                                                                                                                  <div class="codecontainer" id="htmlContainer">
  <span class="containerTitle">Javascript</span>
  <textarea class="code" id="html"></textarea>
</div>

Comment: how to use javascript  in jquery

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking