# How to include CSS in Phoenix EEx templates using inline <style> tags

Tags: css, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to include CSS in Phoenix templates (EEx) so that I can define components (that render on the server) that not only include HTML but also their own CSS. For that I would like to include a  tag with the CSS for that template (component) hoping it would be injected in the `<head>` but that's not what happen. I made a few experiences and wasn't able to achieve that (weird enough when I did that my webpage didn't break and I could see `<head>` and `<style>` tags inside the `<body>`).
A sample `templateXYZ.html.eex` code could be:

```
<style>
   .main {color: red;}
</style>

<div class="main">

    <!-- Html code goes here -->

</div>
```

Note that the main goal of this is to allow me to write all the "component" code in one template (Html, CSS and Javascript - with the later there's no problem so I'm omitting it in the example/question) in a way that I only need to place the template in the proper place inside my other templates (rendering a template inside another template is also not a  problem) and do nothing more (like as when I have a separated CSS file and need to import it in the `<head>`).

As a comparison, I can do what I want in the client side with raw Javascript that places my `<style>` and HTML in the DOM like this:

```
function f_auxButton(imgpath,id){
        if (document.getElementById('auxButtonId')){} // <style> is only created on first component instanciation to avoid duplication
    else {
    $('<style id="auxButtonId">\
       .auxButton {\
            width: 25px;\
            height: 25px;\
            margin: 10px;\
        }\
    <\style>').appendTo("head")}

    return '<img src="'+imgpath+'" class="auxButton" id="'+id+'">'
```

Then I just have to call `<script>f_auxButton(arg1,arg2)</script>` where I want to place the HMTL and I get it (plus the `<style>` tag that goes into the `<head>`.

So, is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Hi Paulo do you have code you could share to help see what you're trying to accomplish? If it's just a matter of including css or javascript, etc. in a template by template basis one possible solution would be to create a shared directory that allowed you to render the shared templates e.g. /web/templates/shared/_styles.html.eex and then within that file you would add the necessary css but within the control flow you need.

Comment: I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html. It gives me a work around, thus not the answer I'm looking for...

Comment: Hi Paulo. I understand what you mean now, I think. You would like to create one (shared template) file that you would embed in other templates that would then add that shared file html and css but the css being applied to the head and the html where you included the shared file.

Comment: html and css but the css being applied to the head and the html where you included the shared file. Unfortunately I'm also new to Phoenix/Elixir and not sure how to do that but you could also ask someone in the #irc-lang channel for help and if you find the solution post it back here.

Comment: @Dikaio Thank you. I'm going to try to figure this out and then I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

**app.html.eex**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <%= render_existing view_module(@conn), "_styles.html", assigns %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <%= render_existing view_module(@conn), "_component.html", assigns %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**/web/templates/shared/_components.html.eex**

```
<%= render MyApp.PageView, "_styles.html" %>
<img src="<%= static_path(MyApp.Endpoint, "/path/example.png")%>", class="auxButton">
```

**/web/templates/page/_styles.html.eex**

```
<style>
  .auxButton {width: 25px;height: 25px;margin: 10px;}
</style>
```

**Final Result**

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>My App</title>
      <style>
        .auxButton {width: 25px;height: 25px;margin: 10px;}
      </style>
    </head>
      <body>
        <div class="main">
          <img src="/path/example.png" class="auxButton">
        </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand what you mean...I edited my question to make it clear. Thank!

Comment: Paulo I think using this method will allow you to do what you're trying to do. [Per the docs](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/0.14.0/Phoenix.View.html#render_existing/3)

Comment: Please see also the changed answer above. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but it does work!

Comment: That's great and I didn't know it could work. Nevertheless, this is half of the job because you're still needing to define the <style> in a separate template/file. My goal was to have HTML and CSS in the same template. I've been trying different approaches with templates and I have still no answer. I think the best would probably work on the view directly and drop the template, but I also feel it's more complicated than the benefits it brings...Thank you Dikaio!

Comment: I see your point Paul! If you find the perfect way to implement this I'd love to see how it's done too. Thanks!