# Path and name of CSS file in production so that I can inline it

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In Phoenix 1.7 the file root.html.heex uses the following line to link to the CSS:

```
<link phx-track-static rel="stylesheet" href={~p"/assets/app.css"} />
```

How can I inline the compiled CSS asset in the production environment within an `<style>` element and still use the above version in the development environment?

I am searching for something like this:

```
<style>
  <%= File.read!("app.css") %>
</style>
```

But that doesn't work. How can I figure out the correct path and filename for the build CSS file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include CSS in Phoenix EEx templates using inline <style> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458293/how-to-include-css-in-phoenix-eex-templates-using-inline-style-tags)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458293/how-to-include-css-in-phoenix-eex-templates-using-inline-style-tags is a different problem/solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% css_file_name = "#{Application.app_dir(:xyz)}/priv/static/assets/app.css" %>

<%= if File.exists?(css_file_name) do %>
  <style>
    <% {:ok, css} = File.read(css_file_name) %>
    <%= raw css %>
  </style>
<% else %>
  <link phx-track-static rel="stylesheet" href={~p"/assets/app.css"} />
<% end %>
```