# C# Display Saxon XSLT transformation result to current ASP.NET container page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, saxon

I've a XML and an XSLT v2.0 transformation to apply to it.
I need to output the resulting HTML (essentialy a table structure for despatch advice document) to the container page.
The container page is an ASP.NET page with some controls and a `Tab` control (from Telerik) that I want to use to put the final document for viewing it.

My problem is that the transformation returns a full HTML page starting from `<html>` tag.
How can I filter only the content that I need?

On another similar project I used an ASP.NET Xml Server Control to both apply the transformation (XSLT v1.0) and automatically obtain the document view. This is the code:

```
XmlDocument xd;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(file))
{
    xd = new XmlDocument();
    xd.Load(ms);
}
XDocument InvoiceXDocument = new XDocument();
using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xd))
{
    nodeReader.MoveToContent();
    InvoiceXDocument = XDocument.Load(nodeReader);
}

invoiceViewer.TransformSource = @"C:\path\to\transformation.xslt";
invoiceViewer.DocumentContent = InvoiceXDocument.ToString(); // XDocument object of the XML invoice
```

Since my new XSLT is a XSLT v2.0 I can't use it anymore. So I switched to Saxon.

This is my actual transformation code using Saxon:

```
Processor processor = new Processor();
XsltCompiler compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
XsltExecutable executable;
executable = compiler.Compile(new Uri(xsltFilePath));

StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
serializer.SetOutputWriter(output);

XsltTransformer transformer = executable.Load();
transformer.SetInputStream(input, new Uri("file:///XSLTValidURI"));
transformer.Run(serializer);

return output.ToString();
```

How can I obtain the same result using Saxon library?

**UPDATE 2016/08/30**

The XML files comes from Peppol European Business Document Service (see [PEPPOL](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_8duswenOAhWFcBoKHbQKBkoQFggtMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.peppol.eu%2F&usg=AFQjCNEbBZTvZ3Ov7-EO-IBiAog1Po6FTA&sig2=bOeEqG2c6JPIdHskQrbp_g&bvm=bv.131286987,d.bGs))

This is the XML to transform (with italian comments).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DespatchAdvice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:DespatchAdvice-2" 
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
    <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:transaction:biitrns016:ver1.0:extended:urn:www.peppol.eu:bis:peppol30a:ver1.0:extended:urn:www.ubl-italia.org:spec:ddt:ver2.1</cbc:CustomizationID>
    <cbc:ProfileID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:profile:bii30:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <!--Identificativo DDT. Obbligatorio-->
    <cbc:ID>DDT-2015-123</cbc:ID>
    <!--Data DDT. Obbligatorio-->
    <cbc:IssueDate>2015-10-29</cbc:IssueDate>
    <!--Orario DDT. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
    <cbc:IssueTime>08:00:50</cbc:IssueTime>
    <!--Campo note in testata. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
    <cbc:Note>Prova Note in Testata</cbc:Note>
    <!--Identificativo riferimento ad un singolo ordine. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
    <cac:OrderReference>
        <cbc:ID>ORD-2015-321</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:IssueDate>2015-10-25</cbc:IssueDate>
        <!--Tipo ordine. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cbc:OrderTypeCode listID="UNCL1001">221</cbc:OrderTypeCode>
    </cac:OrderReference>
    <!--Speditore. Organizzazione che fornisce la merce o servizi. Obbligatorio-->
    <cac:DespatchSupplierParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <!--CF PI speditore. Obbligatorio-->
                <cbc:ID schemeID="IT:VAT">IT123456789</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <!--Azienda speditore. Obbligatorio-->
            <cac:PartyName>
                <cbc:Name>Notier</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
            <!--Contatto persona di riferimento. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
            <cac:Contact>
                <cbc:Name>Magazzino</cbc:Name>
                <cbc:Telephone>05155999</cbc:Telephone>
                <cbc:Telefax>05155999</cbc:Telefax>
                <cbc:ElectronicMail>CasellaPostaSpeditore@indirizzo.it</cbc:ElectronicMail>
            </cac:Contact>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:DespatchSupplierParty>
    <!--Consegnatario. Organizzazione alla quale verranno spediti i prodotti. Obbligatorio-->
    <cac:DeliveryCustomerParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <!--Codice IPA consegnatario Ausl Cesena. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
            <cbc:EndpointID schemeID="IT:IPA">9921:IT0L06J9</cbc:EndpointID>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <!--CF PI consegnatario. Obbligatorio-->
                <cbc:ID schemeID="IT:VAT">123456789</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <!--Azienda consegnatario. Obbligatorio-->
                <cbc:Name>Nome Azienda Consegnatario</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
            <!--Indirizzo consegnatario. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:ID>AB01</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:StreetName>Via</cbc:StreetName>
                <cbc:AdditionalStreetName>Inforazioni aggiuntive all'indirizzo</cbc:AdditionalStreetName>
                <cbc:CityName>Bologna</cbc:CityName>
                <cbc:PostalZone>40100</cbc:PostalZone>
                <cbc:CountrySubentity>BO</cbc:CountrySubentity>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:IdentificationCode listID="ISO3166-1:Alpha2">IT</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
        </cac:Party>
        <!--Contatto persona di riferimento. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cac:DeliveryContact>
            <!--Informazioni persona di riferimento. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
            <cbc:Name>Nome Persona o Magazzino</cbc:Name>
            <cbc:Telephone>05155999</cbc:Telephone>
            <cbc:Telefax>05155999</cbc:Telefax>
            <cbc:ElectronicMail>CasellaPostaConsegnatario@indirizzo.it</cbc:ElectronicMail>
        </cac:DeliveryContact>
    </cac:DeliveryCustomerParty>
    <!--Acquirente. Chi acquista la merce. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
    <cac:BuyerCustomerParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <!--CF PI acquirente. Obbligatorio-->
                <cbc:ID schemeID="IT:CF">123456789</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <!--Azienda acquirente. Obbligatorio-->
                <cbc:Name>Nome Acquirente</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:BuyerCustomerParty>
    <!--Venditore. Chi vende la merce o i servizi. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
    <cac:SellerSupplierParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <!--CF PI venditore. Obbligatorio-->
                <cbc:ID schemeID="IT:VAT">IT123456789</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <!--Azienda venditore. Obbligatorio-->
                <cbc:Name>Nome o Descrizione del Magazzino, Venditore</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
            <!--Contatto persona di riferimento. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
            <cac:Contact>
                <!--Infomrazioni Persona di Riferimento. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
                <cbc:Name>Nome Persona o Magazzino di Riferimento se Presente</cbc:Name>
                <cbc:Telephone>05155999</cbc:Telephone>
                <cbc:Telefax>05155999</cbc:Telefax>
                <cbc:ElectronicMail>CasellaPostaVenditore@indirizzo.it</cbc:ElectronicMail>
            </cac:Contact>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:SellerSupplierParty>
    <!--Committente. Chi eventualmente riceve e consuma la merce. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
    <cac:OriginatorCustomerParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <!--CF PI committente. Obbligatorio-->
                <cbc:ID schemeID="IT:CF">123456789</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <!--Azienda committente. Obbligatorio-->
                <cbc:Name>Nome o Descrizione del Magazzino, Committente</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:OriginatorCustomerParty>
    <!--Gestione spedizione della merce. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
    <cac:Shipment>
        <!--Identificatore spedizione, se non presente ID usare 'NA'. Obbligatorio-->
        <cbc:ID>AB01</cbc:ID>
        <!--Informazioni gestione spedizione. Opzionale-->
        <cbc:Information>Inserire Descrizione Spedizione</cbc:Information>
        <cbc:GrossWeightMeasure unitCode="KGM">100</cbc:GrossWeightMeasure>
        <cbc:GrossVolumeMeasure unitCode="MTQ">15</cbc:GrossVolumeMeasure>
        <cbc:TotalTransportHandlingUnitQuantity>25</cbc:TotalTransportHandlingUnitQuantity>
        <!--Informazioni di trasporto sulla spedizione. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cac:Consignment>
            <cbc:ID>SPED100</cbc:ID>
            <!--Descrizione del veicolo. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
            <cbc:Information>Veicolo ad esempio: AUTOCARRO</cbc:Information>
            <!--Vettore, se diverso da speditore inserirlo. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
            <cac:CarrierParty>
                <cac:PartyName>
                    <!--Reagione sociale del vettore. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
                    <cbc:Name>Vettore: ad esempio SDA</cbc:Name>
                </cac:PartyName>
                <!--Informazioni autista. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
                <cac:Person>
                    <cac:IdentityDocumentReference>
                        <!--Informazioni documento Autista. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
                        <cbc:ID>PAT123456</cbc:ID>
                        <cbc:DocumentType>PATENTE</cbc:DocumentType>
                    </cac:IdentityDocumentReference>
                </cac:Person>
            </cac:CarrierParty>
        </cac:Consignment>
        <!--Gestione Ccnsegna della merce. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cac:Delivery>
            <!--Informazioni sulla consegna della merce. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
            <cbc:TrackingID>Merce10</cbc:TrackingID>
            <!--Periodo stimato sulla consegna della merce. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
            <cac:EstimatedDeliveryPeriod>
                <cbc:StartDate>2015-10-30 </cbc:StartDate>
                <cbc:StartTime>08:30:50</cbc:StartTime>
                <cbc:EndDate>2015-10-31</cbc:EndDate>
                <cbc:EndTime>12:30:50</cbc:EndTime>
            </cac:EstimatedDeliveryPeriod>
            <!--Evasione  della spedizione. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
            <cac:Despatch>
                <!--Periodo e ora evasione spedizione effettiva. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
                <cbc:ActualDespatchDate>2015-10-31</cbc:ActualDespatchDate>
                <cbc:ActualDespatchTime>16:30:30</cbc:ActualDespatchTime>
                <!--Informazioni indirizzo evasione spedizione effettiva. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
                <cac:DespatchAddress>
                    <cbc:ID>234</cbc:ID>
                    <cbc:StreetName>Inserire Indirizzo Principale</cbc:StreetName>
                    <cbc:AdditionalStreetName>Inserire Informazioni Aggiuntive all'Indirizzo</cbc:AdditionalStreetName>
                    <cbc:CityName>Bologna</cbc:CityName>
                    <cbc:PostalZone>40100</cbc:PostalZone>
                    <cbc:CountrySubentity>BO</cbc:CountrySubentity>
                    <cac:Country>
                        <cbc:IdentificationCode listID="ISO3166-1:Alpha2">IT</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                    </cac:Country>
                </cac:DespatchAddress>
            </cac:Despatch>
        </cac:Delivery>
    </cac:Shipment>
    <!--Tabella prodotti richiesti. Obbligatorio-->
    <cac:DespatchLine>
        <!--Identificatore di riga. Obbligatorio-->
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
        <!--Note di riga. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cbc:Note>Inserire Note</cbc:Note>
        <!--Unità di misura e quantità consegnata. Obbligatorio-->
        <cbc:DeliveredQuantity unitCode="NAR" unitCodeListID="UNECERec20">100</cbc:DeliveredQuantity>
        <!--Quantità inevasa. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cbc:OutstandingQuantity unitCode="NAR" unitCodeListID="UNECERec20">20</cbc:OutstandingQuantity>
        <!--Ragione o motivo per la quantità inevasa. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cbc:OutstandingReason>Inserire Motivazione: Ad esempio Difettosa</cbc:OutstandingReason>
        <!--Riferimento a più ordini. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cac:OrderLineReference>
            <!--Riferimento linea d'ordine. Se non valorizzato utilizzare 'NA'. Obbligatorio-->
            <cbc:LineID>1</cbc:LineID>
            <cac:OrderReference>
                <!--Riferimento all'ordine. Obbligatorio-->
                <cbc:ID>ORD-2015-321</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:IssueDate>2015-10-25</cbc:IssueDate>
                <cbc:OrderTypeCode listID="UNCL1001">221</cbc:OrderTypeCode>
            </cac:OrderReference>
        </cac:OrderLineReference>
        <!--Riferimenti aggiuntivi dalle righe dell’avviso spedizione. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cac:DocumentReference>
            <!--Riferimento Linea d'Ordine. Obbligatorio-->
            <cbc:ID>45</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:IssueDate>2015-09-30</cbc:IssueDate>
            <cbc:DocumentType>CIG</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:DocumentReference>
        <!--Riferimenti articolo su riga. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cac:Item>
            <!--Descrizione prodotto. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
            <cbc:Name>ABBA 12CPR RIV 875MG 125MG</cbc:Name>
            <cbc:AdditionalInformation>Principio Attivo:AMOXICILLINA TRIIDRATA/POTASSIO CLAVULANATO</cbc:AdditionalInformation>
            <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
                <!--Codice prodotto. Identificatore dell’articolo secondo il Venditore. Obbligatorio-->
                <cbc:ID>100123</cbc:ID>
            </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
            <cac:StandardItemIdentification>
                <!--Codice prodotto. Identificatore standard per l’articolo. Obbligatorio.-->
                <cbc:ID schemeID="GTIN" schemeAgencyID="9" schemeAgencyName="GS1">036816015</cbc:ID>
            </cac:StandardItemIdentification>
            <!--Istanza specifica dell’articolo. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
            <cac:ItemInstance>
                <!--Informazioni specifici dell'articolo. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
                <cbc:ManufactureDate>2006-06-23</cbc:ManufactureDate>
                <cbc:BestBeforeDate>2020-12-31</cbc:BestBeforeDate>
                <cbc:SerialID>ITA00258</cbc:SerialID>
                <!--Lotto della merce. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
                <cac:LotIdentification>
                    <cbc:LotNumberID>111222333</cbc:LotNumberID>
                    <cbc:ExpiryDate>2017-12-31</cbc:ExpiryDate>
                </cac:LotIdentification>
            </cac:ItemInstance>
        </cac:Item>
        <!--Informazioni particolari sulla spedizione. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
        <cac:Shipment>
            <!--Informazioni sulla spedizione. Se non valorizzato utilizzare 'NA'. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
            <cbc:ID>NA</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:HandlingCode listID="UNCL4079">2</cbc:HandlingCode>
            <!--Unità logistica di trasporto. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
            <cac:TransportHandlingUnit>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="SSCC" schemeAgencyName="GS1">54321</cbc:ID>
                <!--Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
                <cbc:TransportHandlingUnitTypeCode listID="UNECERec21">CT</cbc:TransportHandlingUnitTypeCode>
                <cbc:HazardousRiskIndicator>false</cbc:HazardousRiskIndicator>
                <cbc:ShippingMarks>FIDIA FARMACEUTICI SpA</cbc:ShippingMarks>
                <!--Unità di misura. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
                <cac:MeasurementDimension>
                    <cbc:AttributeID schemeID="UNCL6313">AAB</cbc:AttributeID>
                    <cbc:Measure unitCode="KGM">50</cbc:Measure>
                </cac:MeasurementDimension> 
            </cac:TransportHandlingUnit>
        </cac:Shipment>
    </cac:DespatchLine>
    <cac:DespatchLine>
        <!--Identificatore di riga. Obbligatorio-->
        <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
        <!--Note di riga. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cbc:Note>Inserire Note</cbc:Note>
        <!--Unità di misura e quantità consegnata. Obbligatorio-->
        <cbc:DeliveredQuantity unitCode="NAR" unitCodeListID="UNECERec20">5</cbc:DeliveredQuantity>
        <!--Riferimento a più ordini. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cac:OrderLineReference>
            <!--Riferimento linea d'ordine. Se non valorizzato utilizzare 'NA'. Obbligatorio-->
            <cbc:LineID>2</cbc:LineID>
            <cac:OrderReference>
                <!--Riferimento all'ordine. Obbligatorio-->
                <cbc:ID>ORD-2015-321</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:IssueDate>2015-10-25</cbc:IssueDate>
                <cbc:OrderTypeCode listID="UNCL1001">221</cbc:OrderTypeCode>
            </cac:OrderReference>
        </cac:OrderLineReference>
        <!--Riferimenti aggiuntivi dalle righe dell’avviso spedizione. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cac:DocumentReference>
            <!--Riferimento Linea d'Ordine. Obbligatorio-->
            <cbc:ID>45</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:IssueDate>2015-09-30</cbc:IssueDate>
            <cbc:DocumentType>CIG</cbc:DocumentType>
        </cac:DocumentReference>
        <!--Riferimenti articolo su riga. Opzionale. Se usato inserire informazione-->
        <cac:Item>
            <!--Descrizione prodotto. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
            <cbc:Name>MYLERAN*100CPR RIV 2MG</cbc:Name>
            <cbc:AdditionalInformation>Principio Attivo:BUSULFANO</cbc:AdditionalInformation>
            <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
                <!--Codice prodotto. Identificatore dell’articolo secondo il Venditore. Obbligatorio-->
                <cbc:ID>3698233</cbc:ID>
            </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
            <cac:StandardItemIdentification>
                <!--Codice prodotto. Identificatore standard per l’articolo. Obbligatorio.-->
                <cbc:ID schemeID="GTIN" schemeAgencyID="9" schemeAgencyName="GS1">024787018</cbc:ID>
            </cac:StandardItemIdentification>
            <!--Articoli pericolosi. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
            <cac:HazardousItem>
                <!--Codifiche degli articoli pericolosi. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
                <cbc:ID>3249</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:UNDGCode listID="UNCL8273">ADR</cbc:UNDGCode>
                <cbc:TechnicalName>Medicine, solid, toxic, n.o.s.</cbc:TechnicalName>
                <cbc:CategoryName>ANTIBLASTICI</cbc:CategoryName>
                <cbc:HazardClassID>6.1</cbc:HazardClassID>
            </cac:HazardousItem>
            <!--Istanza specifica dell’articolo. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
            <cac:ItemInstance>
                <!--Informazioni specifici dell'articolo. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
                <cbc:ManufactureDate>2010-05-01</cbc:ManufactureDate>
                <cbc:BestBeforeDate>2022-12-31</cbc:BestBeforeDate>
                <cbc:SerialID>xyz258471</cbc:SerialID>
                <!--Lotto della merce. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
                <cac:LotIdentification>
                    <cbc:LotNumberID>12346987777</cbc:LotNumberID>
                    <cbc:ExpiryDate>2018-12-31</cbc:ExpiryDate>
                </cac:LotIdentification>
            </cac:ItemInstance>
        </cac:Item>
        <!--Informazioni particolari sulla spedizione. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
        <cac:Shipment>
            <!--Informazioni sulla spedizione. Se non valorizzato utilizzare 'NA'. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
            <cbc:ID>NA</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:HandlingCode listID="UNCL4079">2</cbc:HandlingCode>
            <!-- Dettaglio merci sulla temperatura Celsius o Fahrenheit. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
            <cac:GoodsItem>
                <cac:Temperature>
                    <cbc:AttributeID>Conservazione</cbc:AttributeID>
                    <cbc:Measure unitCode="CEL">25</cbc:Measure>
                </cac:Temperature>
                <cac:MinimumTemperature>
                    <cbc:AttributeID>Trasporto</cbc:AttributeID>
                    <cbc:Measure unitCode="CEL">2</cbc:Measure>
                </cac:MinimumTemperature>
                <cac:MaximumTemperature>
                    <cbc:AttributeID>Trasporto</cbc:AttributeID>
                    <cbc:Measure unitCode="CEL">8</cbc:Measure>
                </cac:MaximumTemperature>
            </cac:GoodsItem>
            <!--Unità logistica di trasporto. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
            <cac:TransportHandlingUnit>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="SSCC" schemeAgencyName="GS1">32569</cbc:ID>
                <!--Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
                <cbc:TransportHandlingUnitTypeCode listID="UNECERec21">CT</cbc:TransportHandlingUnitTypeCode>
                <cbc:HazardousRiskIndicator>true</cbc:HazardousRiskIndicator>
                <cbc:ShippingMarks>Marca Prodotto</cbc:ShippingMarks>
                <!--Unità di misura. Opzionale, se usato inserire valori-->
                <cac:MeasurementDimension>
                    <cbc:AttributeID schemeID="UNCL6313">AAB</cbc:AttributeID>
                    <cbc:Measure unitCode="KGM">50</cbc:Measure>
                </cac:MeasurementDimension> 
            </cac:TransportHandlingUnit>
        </cac:Shipment>
    </cac:DespatchLine>
</DespatchAdvice>
```

This is the XSLT file: [UBL2.1_DespatchAdvice.xslt](https://notier.regione.emilia-romagna.it/notier/foglioStile.html?tipoDocumento=DOCUMENTO_DI_TRASPORTO&formato=UBL&versione=2.1)

Comment: I would rather change the XSLT to return only the HTML fragment you are interested in instead of trying to manipulate the string you want to insert. So we would need to see the relevant parts of XML input, XSLT code used, result created and result wanted.

Comment: I've added the XML file and a link to the XSLT because it is too large to be contained in the question.

Comment: Please reduce your examples to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve]

Comment: Well, the first template with `xsl:template match="/"` generates the HTML structure with `html`, `head` and `body` elements, so you would need to edit it to only create the contents of the body I suppose.

Comment: I am not very well versed on XSLT... So I tried to modify the transformation but it now gives me compile error. I removed the `<html><head><body>` containers and replaced them with a `<div>`. I created a scoped `<style>` (see [<style>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html)) inside that `<div>` to mantain all the css definition for the objects.

Comment: Hi, Please can you give details of the compile errors received? If you remove the elements <html><head><body> please take take care to remove the matching closing tag i.e. </html></head></body> further down in the document. In your replacement you need matching <div> ....... </div>.

Comment: Provided Invoice sample is the minimal valid PEPPOL XML document to add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution without need to edit my original XSLT file.

Instead of putting the output inside an `<asp:Xml>` server control on the `DocumentContent` property, I used a `<asp:Literal>` control and the `Text` property.

The whole output HTML will be shown correctly.

Comment: Yes a better solution than the suggested