# Adding CSS linked stylesheet outside of head section

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This might seem a bit unorthodox, but I am trying to use Bootstrap with the website I'm working on now, but don't have access to the head section of the site itself.

Ideally what I'd like to do is to use the Bootstrap CDN, which is available from getbootstrap.

The other option would be to take the CSS I might need from the Bootstrap downloaded CSS files and do the code inline, but this, obviously, would be a bit more work.

So, my question would be -

1) Is it possible to link to the Bootstrap CDN outside of the head?

2) Are there any alternatives I'm not thinking of?

3) Is copying and pasting inline the only way to do it?

We'd need the head developer, with full access, to implement it in the head itself, who has a lot on their plate and this would likely feature quite low on the list of things to do, so if I could do something myself then it'd be great.

Comment: See the first two answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html. The first explains why simply adding `<style>` in `<body>` violates HTML syntax (even though most browsers at this point will allow it), and the second explains how you can use *scoping* to do it without violating the syntax rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include external CSS like Bootstrap in the body section however it is considered as a bad practice. What actually happens when you include the external CSS in your body section is that your content gets posted before getting styled and then gets styled later. In short, what im trying to say is that it works but it has a few drawbacks.

I can not think of any other alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

how are you I know too late to answer but I just wanted to tell my opinion.
I think no, there is no solution to add CSS link stylesheet outside the head section.

with my all love and respect, Ahmad Itani