# Changing the background color of the body while using Bootstraps grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to Bootstraps, trying to use their [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). However I can't change the body background-color now. My stylesheet is working, cause I can change the background color of the container class. I assume something with Bootstraps is overriding my body background-color, and font as well.

Thanks.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
                <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #455A64;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be including your stylesheet *after* Bootstrap's, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
```

Because bootstrap is included last in your code, its CSS is overriding your styles defined in `style.css`. You should typically include your stylesheets after all frameworks/libraries you use so you can properly override styles if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice but you can also do

```
<body style="font-family:Arial; background-color:#455A64">
--------
</body>
```

you can also use [scoped style tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html) in the body, but it's good practice to keep your CSS separate as it allows for easy editing as well as using the same CSS for multiple elements. Hope this helps!