# **CSS code displayd in browser

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
            body * {display:block;color:blue;}
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

my code is above, i realy need `css` in `body`, but in `chrome` it looks like this:

[image]

what's wrong with my code?
and if I change `body * {display:block;color:blue;}` 
to `body input {display:block;color:blue;}` every thing will be ok

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I use `Java` for `web` development, my template engine is `freemaker`
I define a `macro` like this:

```
<#macro Page >
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>  
        <meta ...>
        <link ...>
        <tile ...>
        <script ..>
    </head>
    <body>
        <#nested>
    </body>
    </html>
</#macro>
```

so when I create a page, I can just use

```
<@Page>
    <style>...</style><div...>    <--- this will put in to html body
</@Page>
```

that' why i have to put `css` in `body`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using <style> tags in the <body> with other HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body * {display:block;color:blue;}` will make every in `body` to display in `block`
, and `<style>` is in `body`, so just like `body style {display:block;color:blue;}`

Answer (score 0):

The 'style' tag needs to be placed in the 'head' area:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body * {display:block;color:blue;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Maybe this [Using <style> tags in the <body> with other HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html) post helps you.

Comment: Style tags can be almost anywhere, so explain why please.

Answer (score 0):

I think what java don't understand the '*', try use this:

```
body h1, body h2, body h3, body h4, body h5, body h6, body div, body span, body p, .... etc... {
  display:block;color:blue;
}
```