# Why not put CSS styles in body of HTML?

Tags: seo, fouc

I have seen this topic and have read, for HTML5, it is not good to put CSS styles inside body tag (embedded; not in-line). I know it may cause [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content), and that it won't be "valid" HTML.

I have big limitations working in a CMS in the ck editor, and I have very little choice but to embed a CSS style tag and rules or spend days inlining. The styles should be minimal, but still it is ridiculous. I am overriding already styled content.

None of the pages will validate whether I do this or not, and the flash is a lesser problem than what currently exists.

**The question: Can someone explain exactly (besides the FOUC and not being valid) why is wrong to do this? Is it a problem for SEO?**

Comment: It won't have any influence on SEO. Discussion about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html