# Style in inline HTML not working?

Tags: html, css

Below is the code for selected option in HTML which is working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.Orange{color:Orange;}
.Red{color:Red;}
.Green{color:Green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<SELECT id='select' NAME='select' class="form-select" OnChange='this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className' style='font-family : Arial; font-size : 10px; '>
<OPTION CLASS = 'null' VALUE='' TITLE='' style = 'color:null' SELECTED>
<OPTION CLASS = 'Red' VALUE='108R675' TITLE='Red'  >Red
<OPTION CLASS = 'Green' VALUE='108R723' TITLE='Green' >Green
<OPTION CLASS = 'Green' VALUE='108R725' TITLE='Green' >Green
<OPTION CLASS = 'Orange' VALUE='108R726' TITLE='Orange' >Orange
<OPTION CLASS = 'Green' VALUE='109R642' TITLE='Green' >Green
<OPTION CLASS = 'Orange' VALUE='109R754' TITLE='Orange' >Orange </SELECT>

</body>
</html>
```

But I want to use the style within Selected tags along with font size and family. But if I do that the color style is not working.
I am trying like this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<SELECT id='select' NAME='select' class="form-select" OnChange='this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className' style='font-family : Arial; font-size : 10px; .Orange{color:Orange;}.Red{color:Red;}.Green{color:Green;}'>
<OPTION CLASS = 'null' VALUE='' TITLE='' style = 'color:null' SELECTED>
<OPTION CLASS = 'Red' VALUE='108R675' TITLE='Red'  >Red
<OPTION CLASS = 'Green' VALUE='108R723' TITLE='Green' >Green
<OPTION CLASS = 'Green' VALUE='108R725' TITLE='Green' >Green
<OPTION CLASS = 'Orange' VALUE='108R726' TITLE='Orange' >Orange
<OPTION CLASS = 'Green' VALUE='109R642' TITLE='Green' >Green
<OPTION CLASS = 'Orange' VALUE='109R754' TITLE='Orange' >Orange </SELECT>

</body>
</html>
```

Any idea?

Comment: @Hassan Imam: That's not going to make any difference. This is not XHTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using <style> tags in the <body> with other HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html)

Comment: @BoltClock it's not a solution to the issue OP is facing, it is just odd to see the tag and attribute name in upper case. I have removed the comment as it was misleading.

Comment: @Hassan Imam: That's why I'm telling you it's normal. A little archaic, but normal.

Answer (score 2):

The `style` attribute is being used incorrectly.

This is what you have:

```
<SELECT id='select' 
        NAME='select' 
        class="form-select" 
        OnChange='this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className'
        style='font-family : Arial; font-size : 10px; 
              .Orange{color:Orange;}.Red{color:Red;}.Green{color:Green;}'>
```

You can only insert styles in the `style` attribute. You're including selectors (the classes). That's invalid.

> [**3. Syntax and
>   Parsing**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/#syntax)
>
> The value of the style attribute must match the syntax of the contents
>   of a CSS declaration block (excluding the delimiting braces).

Use the `head` section of the document or an external stylesheet to define selectors.

```
<head>

<style>

  .Orange{color:Orange;}
  .Red{color:Red;}
  .Green{color:Green;}

</style>

</head>
```

Comment: So is there any other to use that within style?

Answer (score 2):

Keep the styles for the colors in the `<head><style>` tag. You can not use the `style` attribute of an element to define CSS classes. Font-family etc. will be inherited from the parent element, so the `<option>` will inherit the font from the `<select>`.

Comment: So is there any other to use that within style?

Answer (score 2):

First Of all Style attribute inline html tag are not used proper

**if u want to use class then use other type of CSS like internal, and external**

you do not use class **inside inline** style attribute

```
<SELECT id='select' 
        NAME='select' 
        class="form-select" 
        OnChange='this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className'
        style='font-family : Arial; font-size : 10px; 
              .Orange{color:Orange;}.Red{color:Red;}.Green{color:Green;}'>
```

**BUT YOU CAN USE IT BELOW METHOD**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
      .Orange{color:Orange;}
      .Red{color:Red;}
      .Green{color:Green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<SELECT id='select' 
    NAME='select' 
    class="form-select Orange Red Green" 
    OnChange='this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className'
    style='font-family : Arial; font-size : 10px;'>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In style tag you cannot include classes:

```
style='font-family : Arial; font-size : 10px; .Orange{color:Orange;}.Red{color:Red;}.Green{color:Green;}'
```

That is the reason it is not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.Orange{color:Orange;}.Red{color:Red;}.Green{color:Green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<SELECT id='select' NAME='select' class="form-select" OnChange='this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className' style='font-family : Arial; font-size : 10px;'>
<OPTION CLASS = 'null' VALUE='' TITLE='' style = 'color:null' SELECTED>
<OPTION CLASS = 'Red' VALUE='108R675' TITLE='Red'  >Red
<OPTION CLASS = 'Green' VALUE='108R723' TITLE='Green' >Green
<OPTION CLASS = 'Green' VALUE='108R725' TITLE='Green' >Green
<OPTION CLASS = 'Orange' VALUE='108R726' TITLE='Orange' >Orange
<OPTION CLASS = 'Green' VALUE='109R642' TITLE='Green' >Green
<OPTION CLASS = 'Orange' VALUE='109R754' TITLE='Orange' >Orange </SELECT>

</body>
</html>
```

Try adding as shown in snippet.

Comment: So is there any other to use that within style?