# Does the `css` argument of `html_page()` work with `build_site(method = 'html')` in blogdown?

Tags: html, css, r, blogdown

In blogdown's documentation, the end of D.8, it says,

> This pair of comments is used to mark the HTML code fragment that should be moved to the `<head>` tag of the final HTML page. Typically this code fragment contains links to CSS and JavaScript files, e.g., those requested by the user via the `css` argument of `html_page()`, or automatically generated when HTML widgets are used in an Rmd document.

and

> For `method = 'html'`, this code fragment is not moved

Does this means the `css` argument of `html_page()` will lose effect when `method = 'html'`? What about CSS and JavaScript files of HTML widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Because CSS (via the `<style>` or `<link>` tag) works in `<body>` in most browsers, even though it does not conform to HTML standards. See [Using <style> tags in the <body> with other HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2830296/559676). JavaScript also works in `<body>`. There is nothing for you to worry about. It would be a shame if HTML widgets do not work with **blogdown**.

The documentation in [Appendix D.8](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/default-template.html) was outdated, and I just updated it.

Comment: Thanks for your generous answer!