# Editable HTML within HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, postmessage

For my job, I'm creating a webpage that has Static HTML templates embedded inside it. The embedded Static HTML page can have parts of the HTML replaced. I'm running into issues because for the parent webpage I only have access to the body and I'm not allowed to upload new HTML documents or any documents on the same domain. I understand that if I could, I would be able to do this all through I-Frames.

What I'm getting at is basically how do I edit Static HTML files that are embedded in Iframes(I own this domain) but within a webpage that I only have access to the body?

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript and Style tags within the body to change the CSS and call other functions to modify HTML.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: A warning though.  Have a read at this before putting CSS style tags in the body. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html

Comment: Inner Html won't work because of Cross-Origin policy