# Possible to generate style tag in PHP? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to add CSS that is dependent on some PHP variables in the code that is generated before a WP_Query loop. Basically I want to use [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) and apply the ID to some elements and then add some media query rules for these elements, possibly as `<style>` tags. I've tried the following, but I'm not sure if style tags that are put in the `<body>` are ignored or not since this is not working.

```
$id = uniqid();

<style>
#<?php echo $id; ?> {
    background: red!important;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
</style>
```

The tag is placed in the DOM, but it's ignored. So I'm either looking for a way to put CSS that is generated in the template, in the `<head>`. Or any other method for adding CSS other than inline on the element itself, since I can't use media queries that way. Just to be clear, the code above is put inside a loop, as I need the meta values from the post in order to generate the CSS.

Or is this just stupid?

Comment: CSS ids can't start with digits ... https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing `<style>` tags [within the `<body>` of your document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/using-style-tags-in-the-body-with-other-html/16844668) is *technically* invalid, but in practice will work almost everywhere.

The problem I suspect you're running into is: the return value of `uniqid()` may begin with a number, and CSS identifiers [cannot begin with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors). So, if you generate an ID like "4b3403665fea6", your CSS might *look* okay, but it will be ignored.

You can fix this by passing a prefix to your call to `uniqid()`, like so:

```
$id = uniqid('id-');
```

...so that `$id` will be a value like "id-4b3403665fea6".

#### Sample demonstrating in-body `<style>`

```html
<head>
<style>
  #id-4b3403665fea6 {
    background: blue;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <div id='id-4b3403665fea6'>Style me!</div>
  <style>
    #id-4b3403665fea6 {
        background: red!important;
        color: #FFF;
        padding: 2px 6px;
        border-collapse: separate;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

Note that the `<div>` winds up with a red background, not blue like the `<head>` style specifies.

Comment: Ah, of course! Should've thought about that. Thanks! I'll try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

```
<?php
$id = uniqid('cnt-');
?>

<style>
    #<?php echo $id; ?> {
        background: red!important;
        color: #FFF;
        padding: 2px 6px;
        border-collapse: separate;
    }
</style>
<div id="<?php echo $id; ?>">Test Content</div>
```